# Changing Grease Pencil stroke placement? (2.8 Beta)

Tags: grease-pencil, 3d-cursor

So, I'm trying to re-draw something I made in the annotation tool (while projecting to the 3D cursor) with the new grease pencil tool (in a grease pencil object, of course), but it doesn't seem to project the same way.
When I was drawing with annotations, there was no problem. I could change it to project to the cursor and sketch (doing this so later I can use the camera for perspective, I'm experimenting with it).
[image: A full screenshot of the Blender workspace.]

and here's what happens in motion (I couldn't figure out how to embed it...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGVTH.jpg
Basically what I'm trying to do is find the options listed [here.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/grease_pencil/drawing/introduction.html#stroke-placement) I need to change the projection to cursor so I can draw on the same "layer" as it is how I would describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to move the Stroke OBJECT (in object mode) to the place where you're drawing, using it like the 3D cursor. Then, it will work like the cursor was before.

Hope that helps-